# Number Format Exception when converting a string

Tags: java, runtime-error, numberformatexception, string-conversion

The following code won't run and keeps throwing a Number Format Exception on the line the error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652" ""

```
intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any advice on the matter

```
private int getPos(String strAlt)
{
 int intAlt;
 int intPos =0;
 intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
 switch (intAlt)
 {
  case 3:
   intPos = 4;
   break;
  case 6:
   intPos = 9;
   break;
  case 9:
   intPos = 17;
   break;   
  case 12:
   intPos = 25;
   break;
  case 18:
   intPos = 33;
   break;   
  case 24:
   intPos = 41;
   break; 
  case 30:
   intPos = 49;
   break;   
  case 34:
   intPos = 56;
   break;   
  case 39:
   intPos = 63;
   break;  
 }
 return intPos;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or SOP statement to see what the value of `strAlt` is.

Comment: I agree with @Code-Guru, except I just noticed that OP states that it won't compile.  OP, you need to clarify - throwing an exception only happens at runtime.  Does it not compile, or does it throw an exception when you run it?

Comment: Okay, to clarify, does your code fail to compile? or does it throw a NumberFormatExceptions? It can't do both! Either way, please post the *exact* error message so that we can help.

Comment: It throws the error one I run the program and stops it early sorry about that it throws "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652" "

Comment: That input string cannot be converted to an integer, it has letters, symbols and spaces in it.  Was the string supposed to be like that?  Either you have a bug in your code or `parseInt` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: How so you want to convert `SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652` into a int?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html ?

Comment: I want it to take the first 2 numbers to turn into an int so 19, 18 , 15, 12 in order to state the position of them in the string when case 3 it should be the first int of 19 which makes pos 4 when case 5 it should be 18 which is at pos 9

Comment: @Alex - Then you need to code such split. `parseInt` method parses one number.

Comment: What method should I use to code it so it looks at the first 2 digits of each set of numbers?

Comment: @AlexChapp no current method invented, you should write your own.

Comment: @AlexChapp You need more than just a single method to do what you want. You have described in words what you want to do, now I suggest you look at the API docs for `String` to find methods that will help you translate those steps into Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass "SAN 1905 1808+24 1512+17 1209+10 1708-06 2016-16 211831 211941 192652" into getPos(String strAlt), it will execute:

```
intAlt = Integer.parseInt(strAlt);
```

Of course it will throw exception.
[See this doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm)